# Storyboarding: How to keep Navigation Controller from defaulting to Table View Controller

Tags: xcode

Am working with my first storyboard application and am having a problem. When I drag a navigation controller to my layout, the root controller always ends up as a table view controller, when all I want is just a basic view controller.

How do I keep the navigation controller from setting up the root view controller as a root table view controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has changed sometime between Xcode 4.2 and 4.3.3. I had Xcode 4.2 on another computer running Snow Leopard, and adding a navigation controller sets up a regular view controller as the root view controller, but Xcode 4.3.3 on my main development machine running Lion behaves as you described--it adds a table view controller.

I'm not aware of any way to change this (maybe Xcode ninjas could hack some templates?), but of course you can just delete the table view controller and add a new regular view controller, and set its custom class. Then you Control-drag from the navigation controller to your new view controller, and select "Relationship - Root View Controller" from the pop-up menu (this used to say "... - rootViewController" in Xcode 4.2).

Erica Sadun's "The iOS 5 Developer's Cookbook" relies on the old Xcode 4.2 behavior in Chapter 4's storyboard walkthrough, but I managed to complete it with no issues using the workaround I described above, which you probably have found already. But if not, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am now running 4.3.2 on Lion and will try this next time I work on a project which involves using Storyboard. Most of the time Apple's Xcode development tools group makes good changes, but sometimes they make changes which just make me scratch my head. Again, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple add navigation controller to the storyboard
after that delete link shown between viewcontroller and navigation controller
then add tableview controller to the story board
control click on the navigation view and realease on the tableview controller
in the apperaing menu select relationship segue as rootviewcontroller